# WiFi hard-blocked on GNOME

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, gnome, opensuse, wifi-configuration

Every once in a while I try out a new linux distro.
And the same problem occurs over and over again when I install a distribution using GNOME: my Wifi is hard-blocked.
I try unblocking it with `rfkill`, but it doesn't work.
I have no idea why my Intel Centrino 1000 appears to be hard-blocked on: Fedora(GNOME), OpenSUSE(GNOME), but works totaly fine on Ubuntu, Manjaro(KDE), ElementaryOS and OpenSUSE(KDE).
I have an Lenovo Ideapad Z570